# i have an issue on select all in collectionviewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

i have button this button is select all cells in collectionView it is work ok but the problem is when i select all cells it take huge memory i don't know why please can tell me how can i select all cells in collectionView without take huge memory

the following my code:

func selectAllCells() {

```
                 var i = 0
                 while i < self.collectionView.numberOfItemsInSection(0) {
                // her i get the index path
                let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: i, inSection: 0)
                self.collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: false)

                self.collectionView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast
                self.collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
                self.dictionaryOfSelectItem.updateValue(i, forKey: i)
                let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! AlbumImagesCollectionViewCell
                cell.imageViewCheck.hidden = false
                self.dictionaryOfSelectItem.updateValue(i, forKey: i)

                i = i + 1

                }

                self.moveOutlet.enabled = true
                self.exportOutlet.enabled = true
                self.deleteOutlet.enabled = true


}
```

Thanks advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a global variable called selectAll, somewhere before viewDidLoad()

Inside your selectAll() function, set the variable you just created to true.

```
self.selectAll = true;
//Now call your reload function for your collectionView. 
self.collectionView.reloadData
```

Now in your cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
   if selectAll {
        cell.selected = true;
} else {
        cell.selected = false;
}
```

When the user deselects "Select All" button, or does something else, then set selectAll to **false** and reload the data again.

If you want to perform anything with every cell once they are all selected, do it in the cellForItemAtIndexPath function.

Comment: thank you very much my friend but please tell me when i call reload function in view will appear or in my specific function?

Comment: You call the reload function inside your selectAll() function.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I try to use your approach to select all cell in my collection view. It perform well but after select all cell. I can not deselect the single cell. This is strange because I can select/ deselect before all cell been selected. How to do the deselect function?